# How can I run Slack in Night Mode on Desktop app

Tags: themes, desktop, slack

Slack themes are available in the web app using Stylish see https://userstyles.org/styles/browse?search_terms=slack

However there must be a way to use them on the Desktop application.  What is the hack?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UPDATED LATEST!  Slack desktop app now supports dark mode natively!
Just got to preferences `cmd+,` and select Themes > Dark

UPDATED, previous hacks stopped working with release of 4.0.0.

This solution works as of July 18, 2019

see https://github.com/LanikSJ/slack-dark-mode

You may need to see instructions on https://github.com/LanikSJ/slack-dark-mode/issues/80

I will likely update this answer again when I have time to fork the repo I've posted above and improve upon it.

Answer (score 2):

I've written a sort of small "plugin framework", where you just run a shell script to patch your slack install, and then you get the ability to enable any number of "plugins" I've written for the desktop app, one of which is a dark theme.  There are instructions in the README if you'd like to load your own CSS files you've found elsewhere as well.

https://github.com/glajchs/slack-customizations

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://gist.github.com/hon2a/0679f72bd990fc72cc91046455f736e6)'s my script to toggle between light and dark mode automatically at sunrise/sunset. Append the script at the end of `/Applications/Slack.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar.unpacked/src/static/ssb-interop.js` and don't forget to update the `LOCATION` based on your actual location.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', async function() {
  // supply your location here, use e.g. https://www.latlong.net/ to find it
  const LOCATION = [50.075539, 14.437800]
  const MS_IN_DAY = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000

  const initTheme = themeCssUrl => new Promise(resolve => $.ajax({
    url: themeCssUrl,
    success: css => {
      const styleJqueryEl = $('<style>').html(css).appendTo('head')
      const styleElement = styleJqueryEl[0]
      styleElement.disabled = true
      resolve(styleElement)
    }
  }))

  const loadTimeInfo = ([latitude, longitude]) => new Promise(resolve => $.ajax({
    // courtesy of https://sunrise-sunset.org/api
    url: `https://api.sunrise-sunset.org/json?lat=${latitude}&lng=${longitude}&formatted=0`,
    success: ({ results: { sunrise, sunset } }) => resolve({
      sunrise: Number(new Date(sunrise)),
      sunset: Number(new Date(sunset)),
      expires: Math.ceil(Date.now() / MS_IN_DAY) * MS_IN_DAY
    })
  }))

  const updateTheme = (styleElement, timeInfo) => {
    const now = Date.now()
    const { sunrise, sunset } = timeInfo
    styleElement.disabled = now >= sunrise && now < sunset
  }

  const darkModeStyle = await initTheme('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mattiacantalu/Slack-Dark-Mode/master/dark-mode.css')
  let timeInfo = await loadTimeInfo(LOCATION)
  updateTheme(darkModeStyle, timeInfo)
  // can't simply `setTimeout` to the next update time - if the app is sleeping at that time, the call seems to be lost
  window.setInterval(async () => {
    if (Date.now() > timeInfo.expires) {
      timeInfo = await loadTimeInfo(LOCATION)
    }
    updateTheme(darkModeStyle, timeInfo)
  }, 5 * 60 * 1000)
})
```

*Note that as this process directly modifies the application files, it needs to be repeated after every Slack update.*

Comment: Pretty cool. You might want to not use the `cdn.rawgit` but rather just `rawgit` see https://github.com/rgrove/rawgit/blob/master/FAQ.md but basically because of caching. Another thing to keep in mind is that https://rawgit.com/ is in sunset mode. There's time, but I'll also need to update my code at some point.

Comment: @lacostenycoder Thanks for the tip. You can't actually switch to just `rawgit` for this resource now, precisely because of the EOL. I've updated the URL to link directly to GitHub. (The limitation that `rawgit` aimed to overcome is irrelevant in this case anyway, as the fetched content is used as plain text.)

Comment: Yeah I saw the EOL notice.  I switched to jsdelivr with the handy https://www.jsdelivr.com/rawgit tool.

Comment: are you using jsdelivr?  I seemed to have problems with it.

Comment: @lacostenycoder No, I'm not. As explained in my previous comment, my patch can (and does) fetch directly from GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

This answer does not solve the desktop app question but can be used as a browser only based solution.

1. Use Chrome instead of downloadable Slack app
2. Install [Dark Reader chrome add-on](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dark-reader/eimadpbcbfnmbkopoojfekhnkhdbieeh)
3. Open Slack url (eg. https://team_name.slack.com/) in Chrome instead of app

Comment: Did you read the actual question?  It specifically asks how to do this in the DESKTOP app.

Comment: @lacostenycoder Yes I did read the question. I'm posting for folks that don't have the constraint of the desktop app. The steps I put are significantly easier than any convoluted hack done with Slack's desktop app. This is a community and the answer wasn't for you, but for folks that are willing to deal with a browser tab for the sake of convenience.

Comment: There are other reason for using the desktop app other then just not being in a browser tab. So yeah, perhaps simplest, IF you don't need stand alone app.  Your answer should be the answer to "How do I make almost any website night mode?" There is nothing specific to slack here.